# Is it possible to create Sort By slicer in Power BI?

Tags: powerbi, dax, powerbi-desktop

I have stacked bar chart with 4 values. 
The chart need to be filtered by one of those value.

Is it possible to have like a slicer but when picking a value it would be sorting chart?

Or maybe some other workaround that would be easy for end user to sort visual?

Thanks

[image]

Answer (score 0):

I think you could do this if you sort by a measure that ranks the names dependent on your slicer selection.

1. Create a measure that reads in your `Sort By` selection and calculates the ranks accordingly using a `SWITCH` function for the different options.
2. Add that measure as a tooltip to your visual.
3. You should now have the ability to sort the visual on that measure.

Not super elegant, but not too bad of a workaround.